# Get all WHERE cases in one query

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I've got this query

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN weapon_stats ON users.id = weapon_stats.zp_id
WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 26
ORDER BY weapon_stats.kills DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The problem it's that y need to get results changing where from 1 to 30, thats odd..

Is it possible to get all the results in one query?

I want to get each user with most kills with every weapon

weapon 1

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN weapon_stats ON users.id = weapon_stats.zp_id
WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 01
ORDER BY weapon_stats.kills DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

weapon 2

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN weapon_stats ON users.id = weapon_stats.zp_id
WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 02
ORDER BY weapon_stats.kills DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select U.name, W.weapon, W.kills
FROM users U
INNER JOIN weapons W on W.zp_id = U.id
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT WW.weapon, MAX(WW.kills) AS kills 
    FROM weapons WW 
    WHERE WW.weapon BETWEEN 1 AND 30
    GROUP BY WW.weapon) K
  ON W.kills = K.kills AND W.weapon = K.weapon
```

I'm sure it can be made faster by optimization but this finally works

[jsfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b5db/11)

Comment: I need to get the results of each query, from 0 value to 1. I don't want to make 30 queryes (WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 1, WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 2, WHERE weapon_stats.weapon = 3) etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE weapon_stats.weapon BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'changing where from 1 to 30' but see the following:

[..]WHERE wearpon_stats.weapon BETWEEN 1 AND 30;

More here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for, can't you do the following?

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN weapon_stats ON users.id = weapon_stats.zp_id
WHERE weapon_stats.weapon BETWEEN 1 and 30
ORDER BY weapon_stats.kills DESC
LIMIT 1;
```